# Cannot connect to local mongodb via Internet route

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have a mongodb instance running inside a container on my host server (say `host1`). The docker port has been map from container's port to host port. In my case `27017`. Configuration is as below.

I have a webapp running inside another container. If I put the webapp container on another server, say `host2`, then it can access that mongodb, but if it's on `host1`, it can't. Since I want the webapp to always treat mogodb as an Internet connection to allow using the webapp docker on any host, independent of the mongodb host, I don't want to bind the webapp connection to host via LAN network.

`telnet` on my laptop to that mongodb works, but not from inside another docker on `host1`. Anyone idea where I screwed up? thanks

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
 storage:
   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
   journal:
    enabled: true
   wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 48

# where to write logging data.
 systemLog:
   destination: file
   logAppend: false
   path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
  net:   
    port: 27017   
    bindIpAll: true


# how the process runs
 processManagement:
   timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
   authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

For docker port mapping:

```
0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/udp
```

**Edits:**
I use mongoose with mongo connection string, from both `host1` and `host2`.

The docker network driver is `Overlay`.

This is the docker network config of the webapp:

```
{
        "Name": "clientA_webnet",
        "Id": "pr4i54oqo6snwc9jev2zs4tq2",
        "Created": "2019-07-17T10:00:55.361594601+07:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.6.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.6.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "19cf98a368b5fe515eaaba90e7e036d26925af06196beb1027efa1d982778bb6": {
                "Name": "clientA_webapp_container",
                "EndpointID": "1a326fc3226cb3b9dc85c3426ca9cfdf8e4543366b07e67e83c10b7f924ab538",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3bf158bbc7237a98c4607049b8955b7e25b3e0cbde63f7165f7c6d1f86d5f5a2": {
                "Name": "clientA_redis_container",
                "EndpointID": "4f294d55f27bb02e9adaac27658b2c7d28bf0a1b5d397c8e5a905e896925db10",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7d4cfe90ad1d5b29aef135695a517af17c80a5602008fe2125152c0892242e54": {
                "Name": "clientA_nginx_container",
                "EndpointID": "18a8d5f2c48f7e056585f302c0e1f654e170fac13ef033f2ecd3a0477bd74d57",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:06:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.6.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4103"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "8d418ecd9f27",
                "IP": "x.x.x.x"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Below is the mongodb network config

```
{
        "Name": "common_net",
        "Id": "e2c0a6261df67d429e24ae3ac4da82dd6604fb7e1a3d788ce81199391e1d0291",
        "Created": "2019-03-04T11:12:19.332798004+07:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "cdca734916358983fd77f4b9b64434d163a67f146c0c152bdb178502db89d37b": {
                "Name": "common_mongo_container",
                "EndpointID": "253a7ca61a065de90912aaa8b9dc76f0d491aa10bb93ecba4a71d6417f48a3c4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.10/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

Below is the way I connect to mongodb where `x.x.x.x` is the real Internet IP address of the server (in this case `host1`)

```
mongodb: 'mongodb://username:password@x.x.x.x:27017/dashboard'
```

Comment: How you connect to the db? both from host2 and host1 please. What's the docker network driver on host1.

Comment: @AlexBlex I've updated my question. Do you need anything else? Tks

Comment: Thank Taxi, I don't, you do =) There are 3 things involved - config of the db, config of docker network, connection string from application.  The mongo config looks fine, albeit insecure. I'm afraid you need to share docker network info and exact connection string without passwords of course. "mongoose" is just doesn't say anything. It won't be useless to add the connection error you have either.

Comment: @AlexBlex sure I do, :D. Just updated again, any more tip? Thanks

Comment: So I understand it as mongo is on a standalone container outside the swarm, uses bridge network. I tried it locally, it works with such setup.

Comment: Check iptables on your host1 system. It's likely the local mongo container is blocked by INPUT chain whilst requests from other hosts pass thru NAT

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks, work like a champ! Forgot to reply to you earlier!

Comment: @AlexBlex by the way, you told me my mongo config looks insecure, can you please point me to somewhere to read up on that? Thanks